# Expected value of times we roll a pair of dice

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I am trying to solve this using a geometric series. Pretty much the question goes like this: We roll a pair of fair dice repeatedly and independently and stop as soon as the sum of the dice is equal to 7.

My random variable is: $X =$ the number of times we roll.

To calculate the expected value of time we will roll I do somehting like this:

$$E(X) = X_1P_1+X_2P_2+X_3P_3+...+X_nP_n$$

The probability or rolling a 7 using 2 dice is $\frac 6 {36}=\frac1 6$ so then,

$$E(X)=1*\frac 1 6+2*\frac 1 6+3*\frac 1 6+...+n*\frac 1 6$$

Not to sure about this:

$$E(X)=\frac 1 6 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n*\frac 1 6$$

And if this is the correct sequence what can I do with it next?

Answer (score 3):

No, the probability that it takes you one turn (meaning you roll the pair of dice) is $\frac{6}{36}$. The probability that you take two turns (roll the pair once and fail, roll the pair again and succeed), that is $\frac{30}{36}\cdot\frac{6}{36}$. Thus, you succeed on $k$th roll is
$$P(X = k) = \left(\frac{30}{36}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{6}{36}\right).\tag{$\star$}$$
Then, calculating the expectation would be
$$E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X = k).$$
You can proceed like this, or you can notice (as $(\star)$ suggests) that 
$$X\sim\text{Geom}(p = 6/36)$$
over $\{1,2,\dotsc\}$. Therefore
$$E[X] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{36}{6} = 6.$$
You can check your method against this.

Comment: This is making sense the only thing I am a little confused about is how you got the $\frac {30}{36} * \frac{6}{36}$

Comment: $P(X=2) = P(\text{Fail, Succeed}) = P(\text{Fail})P(\text{Succeed}) = \frac{30}{36}\cdot\frac{6}{36}$. Since the events are independent, you can multiply the probabilities. Failing means the sum was not equal to $7$. If you say that 6 of the sums equal 7, then 30 of the sums do not equal 7.

Comment: Why you put a _k_ before $P(X=k)$? Maybe Im overlooking something but to me the probability is just $E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X = k)$

Comment: [Discrete case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_countable_case).

Comment: If you add over all possible values, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X = k) = 1.$

Comment: I am still a little confused about this. Here is my revised sequence $$(\frac{30}{36})^0(\frac {6}{36})+(\frac{30}{36})^1(\frac {6}{36})+(\frac{30}{36})^2(\frac {6}{36})+(\frac{30}{36})^3(\frac {6}{36})+...+(\frac{30}{36})^n(\frac {6}{36})$$I am trying to massage this into a formula that looks like this: $$p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$ so then I can get this $$p\frac {1} {1-x}$$ whenever I do this I end up with 1 even though your answer is 6.

Comment: You want the *expectation* which will be $1(\frac{30}{36})^0(\frac {6}{36})+2(\frac{30}{36})^1(\frac {6}{36})+3(\frac{30}{36})^2(\frac {6}{36})+4(\frac{30}{36})^3(\frac {6}{36})+...+(n-1)(\frac{30}{36})^n(\frac {6}{36})$

Comment: @Steph I'm not sure what you are doing. To get the expectation the sum is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot \left(\frac{30}{36}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{6}{36}\right)$. What you are doing is
$$p\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k = p[-1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k] = \frac{6}{36}[1-\frac{1}{1-30/36}] = \frac{6}{36}[-1+\frac{36}{6}] = \frac{30}{36},$$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @probablyme Ah thanks! I was using the incorrect sum. What I wanted is the expectation sum that you showed!

Answer (score 0):

The probability of rolling a 7 at any point is $\frac { 6}{36}$.

Since we roll the dice until the first sum appears that is 7 we end up with a geometric series: $$E(X)=\frac {6}{36}*\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k*(\frac {30}{36})^{k-1}$$

Taking the derivative of the sum we get $$\frac {6}{36}* \frac 1 {(1- \frac {30} {36})^2}$$ which equals to $6$.